# Does anything look wrong with my MLA 8 citations

Tags: mla

[image: citations]

I have a general question about MLA. If you're citing an article and there is only one edition of the article, do you have to put "1st ed.," or can you leave it blank?

Answer (score 1):

Edition is only used to distinguish sources where there have been various updates or new editions. If a source was only published once with no susequent changes/reissues then it is generally inappropriate to use as part of your citation.

The exception is when the publisher dictates a format for citation and it is specified there (this usually means further editions are already planned).